# Why can I not get 4k?

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi

I'm struggling with finding the origin of this issue, I figured you guys know more than me so I'll try asking here!

I recently bought a cintiq pro 24, which is capable of 4k. The requirements are 'USB type C port (supporting DisplayPort Alternate Mode) or DisplayPort or HDMI 2.0 port (required for 3840 x 2160 resolution)'.

My PC is acer aspire XC - 705, the processor is intel core i5-4460 3.20 ghz 8gb ram, and the graphics card is intel hd graphics 4600. I know this isn't great haha it's a bit old now, but it still works fine with everything so I'd love to avoid upgrading it currently to give my bank account a bit of a rest. I've asked around about this issue and received conflicting advice, someone said the graphics card should be able to run 4k so I'm a bit lost!

I'm using the cable that came with the cintiq so that shouldn't be a problem. I can't see a displayport or usbc port on the pc so my only option is hdmi. the ONLY thing I can think of is that the port on the computer isn't hdmi2, but I can't find anything in the pc specs, or anything online about how to see what type of hdmi it is.

If anyone here could help I'd be so grateful(:

Comment: Due to the fact you don't have a Display Port and your GPU does not support HDMI 2.0 then you cannot get 4k, even if you did have the Display Port, the `intel hd graphics 4600` isn't powerful enough for 4k

Answer (score 1):

This article from Intel support, [Not able to Select 4K Resolution at 60Hz](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000023945/graphics-drivers.html), covers the basics of what's needed for 4K.

Your monitor can accept a variety of inputs for 4K: HDMI, DisplayPort, or USB-C with DisplayPort Alternate Mode. The [specs](https://www.wacom.com/en-us/products/pen-displays/wacom-cintiq-pro-24#Specifications) suggest what it can do with HDMI (4K resolution with the capabilities associated with HDMI 2.0), but they don't actually specify all the detail.  The specs also describe the included HDMI cable as HDMI 2.0, which will handle standard 4K.  So let's assume the monitor and cable are up to the task.

The leaves your PC.  I couldn't find its specs at the Acer web site, but I found them in a [Walmart ad](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Acer-Aspire-XC-705-Desktop-PC-with-Intel-Core-i3-4160-Dual-Core-Processor-6GB-Memory-1TB-Hard-Drive-and-Windows-10-Home-Monitor-Not-Included/48318173).  Its native configuration doesn't offer DisplayPort or USB-C with Alternate Mode.  It looks like the chipset supports DisplayPort and 4K, but the computer doesn't include the port.  The [Intel HD Graphics 4600](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/80817/intel-core-i5-4460-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-40-ghz.html) supports 4K60 in some modes, but its HDMI is only v1.4.

It will support 4K30 (which many people would find too slow a frame rate).  HDMI 1.4 (the spec, I don't know about your chipset specifically), can handle 4K60 with highly compressed (lossy compression) color information (see 4:2:0 chroma discussion on [Chroma Subsampling
4:4:4 vs 4:2:2 vs 4:2:0](https://www.rtings.com/tv/learn/chroma-subsampling)).  That color compression can be fine for some applications but not others (among the latter being many of the applications for a PC monitor).

So as the computer came originally configured, you might actually be able to do some limited 4K resolution (4K movies or TV content could be fine), but it doesn't support full 4K.

Comment: This is interesting! I'd be using the monitor specifically for illustration, mainly photoshop. i'm not sure if framerate is important or not for something like that, but I'd imagine colour information is? I think as the cintiq specifies it needs hdmi 2, that might be why 4k isn't at all possible, even though with a different setup and a normal monitor it could work for some content? not sure but that's what im guessing! thank you for the input(: